# Scrambled video when using Logitech USB headset

Tags: video, webcam, skype, headset

When I make a Skype video call *and* the Logitech USB headset is selected as sound device, the video is scrambled. It normalizes even during the call as soon as I select the built-in sound device. Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue?

I have a Lenovo T400 running Ubuntu Oneiric and using the latest Skype 2.2.0.35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has vanished with Ubuntu 12.10.